# Clear file input field after file selected using JQuery on select change

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Using a Jquery plugin called filestyle from: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle.  I have a select box with an id of adtype. If the selected option has a value of 7, it'll disable the file input with the id of 'adfile'.

The problems becomes when a user has already selected a file. I cant find a way to clear the file input and then disable it. $('#adfile').val(''); does not work.

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
  $('#adtype').change(function(){
    if($('#adtype option:selected').val()==="7"){
      $('#adfile').val('');
      $("#adfile").prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
      $("#adfile").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="someform" action="somepage" method="post">
  <select name="selectstuff" id="adtype">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
  </select>

  <input type="file" id="adfile" value="" />

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used 
`$('#adfile').val('');` and `$('#adfile').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/qrLyM/)

NOTE: filestyle plugin removes `id,name` attributes from the file input element and adds `file` as class. I'm accessing this element with reference to the form.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, although it wont work on my page. I believe the filestyle plugin from: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle is interfering with clearing the file input field. If I remove the filestyle plugin, I can clear the field. Thanks.

Comment: you should have mentioned about that in your question, you could have got a more accurate answer

Comment: Thanks to you I figured it out. Set the .file class value to "" AND disable the file input id adfile" $('#addaduploadform .file').val('');
$('#adfile').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":file").filestyle('clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#adtype').change(function(){
        if($('#adtype option:selected').val()==="7"){
            $('#adfile').remove();
            $('#file_div').html('<input type="file" id="adfile" value="" />')
            $("#adfile").prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $("#adfile").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="signup">
        <form id="someform" action="somepage" method="post">
       <select name="selectstuff" id="adtype">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="5">five</option>
<option value="7">seven</option>
</select>
        <div id="file_div">
         <input type="file" id="adfile" value="" />

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that technique yesterday. Won't work. I'll just chalk this up to the filestyle plugin interfering with the other JQuery. Thanks for the effort

Comment: i have checked it in ie and all other browser.it works fine just add jquery.js in this code and test.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$("#Elementid").val(null);
```